# Copy values from multiple sheets to one sheet

Tags: excel, vba, copy-paste

Trying to find a streamlined way to accomplish the below code...

Copy and Paste cell values from several different cells on two separate sheets to another sheet to the next available row...

The second part of the code works great...once a row is established, and RW variable identifies the row number, it will update fine.

The problem is the initial copy paste. The code works, but runs very, very slow. Looking for an alternative method to accomplish the same thing that would run faster and cleaner.

```
    Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Dim response As Integer
    Dim lkup As String
    Dim SourceWS    As Worksheet, DestWS As Worksheet
    Dim SourceRng   As Range, DestCell   As Range
    Dim lloop As Long
    Set SourceWS = Sheets("Leave Calculations") ' Source Sheet
    Set DestWS = Sheets("Historical") 'Destination Sheet
    lkup = Sheets("Formulas").Range("V5").Value


response = MsgBox("Are you ready to print?", vbYesNo, "PRINT SHEET?")

If response = 6 Then

Application.Dialogs(xlDialogPrinterSetup).Show

ActiveSheet.PrintOut

On Error Resume Next
With Sheets("historical")
    Dim Rw2 As Long, Fnd2 As Range
Set Fnd2 = .Range("B:B").Find(lkup, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlPart, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious)
 If Not Fnd2 Is Nothing Then
     Rw2 = Fnd2.Row
 'Else
     'MsgBox lkup & " not found in Historical Data"
 End If
             If Rw2 = 0 Then


        ' Copy data to Historical form


        Application.ScreenUpdating = 0


            With SourceWS
            Set DestCell = DestWS.Range("a" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1)
            For lloop = 1 To 30 ' number must match total cells in range
                Set SourceRng = Choose(lloop, Sheets("Formulas").Range("v4"), Sheets("Formulas").Range("v5"), Sheets("Formulas").Range("v2"), Sheets("Leave Calculations").Range("b6"), _
                Sheets("Leave Calculations").Range("c6"), Sheets("Leave Calculations").Range("d6"), Sheets("Leave Calculations").Range("d11"), Sheets("Formulas").Range("v3"), _
                Sheets("Leave Calculations").Range("e15"), Sheets("Leave Calculations").Range("e16"), Sheets("Leave Calculations").Range("e21"), _
                Sheets("Formulas").Range("b39"), Sheets("Formulas").Range("b57"), Sheets("Formulas").Range("c57"), Sheets("Formulas").Range("V10"), _
                Sheets("Formulas").Range("B1"), Sheets("Formulas").Range("B9"), Sheets("Formulas").Range("B10"), Sheets("Formulas").Range("V22"), _
                Sheets("Formulas").Range("V15"), Sheets("Formulas").Range("V16"), Sheets("Formulas").Range("V17"), Sheets("Formulas").Range("V18"), _
                Sheets("Formulas").Range("V19"), Sheets("Formulas").Range("A2"), Sheets("Formulas").Range("V20"), Sheets("Formulas").Range("A2"), Sheets("Formulas").Range("A2"), _
                Sheets("Formulas").Range("B58"), Sheets("Formulas").Range("v21"), Sheets("Formulas").Range("A2"), Sheets("Formulas").Range("v23")) 'adjust the range
                SourceRng.Copy
                DestCell.Offset(, lloop - 1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
            Next lloop
            End With

                With Application
                    .CutCopyMode = 0
                    .ScreenUpdating = 0
                End With
     Else:
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of pasting cell by cell you can collect all the values in an array then assign it when you're done looping over the input ranges.

```
Const NUM_VALS as Long  = 30

dim vals() '<< array for your data

With SourceWS
        Set DestCell = DestWS.Range("a" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1)
        Redim vals(1 to 1, 1 to NUM_VALS)

        For lloop = 1 To NUM_VALS  ' number must match total cells in range

            Set SourceRng = Choose(lloop, Sheets("Formulas").Range("v4"), Sheets("Formulas").Range("v5"), Sheets("Formulas").Range("v2"), Sheets("Leave Calculations").Range("b6"), _
            Sheets("Leave Calculations").Range("c6"), Sheets("Leave Calculations").Range("d6"), Sheets("Leave Calculations").Range("d11"), Sheets("Formulas").Range("v3"), _
            Sheets("Leave Calculations").Range("e15"), Sheets("Leave Calculations").Range("e16"), Sheets("Leave Calculations").Range("e21"), _
            Sheets("Formulas").Range("b39"), Sheets("Formulas").Range("b57"), Sheets("Formulas").Range("c57"), Sheets("Formulas").Range("V10"), _
            Sheets("Formulas").Range("B1"), Sheets("Formulas").Range("B9"), Sheets("Formulas").Range("B10"), Sheets("Formulas").Range("V22"), _
            Sheets("Formulas").Range("V15"), Sheets("Formulas").Range("V16"), Sheets("Formulas").Range("V17"), Sheets("Formulas").Range("V18"), _
            Sheets("Formulas").Range("V19"), Sheets("Formulas").Range("A2"), Sheets("Formulas").Range("V20"), Sheets("Formulas").Range("A2"), Sheets("Formulas").Range("A2"), _
            Sheets("Formulas").Range("B58"), Sheets("Formulas").Range("v21"), Sheets("Formulas").Range("A2"), Sheets("Formulas").Range("v23")) 'adjust the range

            vals(1, lloop) = SourceRng.Value '<< add value to array


        Next lloop
        DestCell.Resize(1, NUM_VALS).Value = vals '<< assign the array
 End With
```

Also consider creating some variables for your worksheets to avoid all that repetition.

Comment: You are awesome! I still get a little confused with some of this stuff, so appreciate the help immensely!